# Is Energy relative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames

Suppose a ball have velocity and moving in space.
kinetic energy of ball is something numerical value but when we see the ball in the frame of ball, the velocity became zero also kinetic energy is zero.
how it is possible?
Energy is dependent on frame or not?

Comment: Read the 4th paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, energy is *relative*. Its value — like the value of various other physical quantities: velocity, momentum, angular momentum, electric field, magnetic field, etc. — depends on what inertial frame it is measured in.

Note that the *conservation* of energy in each inertial frame does not imply the *frame-invariance* of energy.

Comment: it means exact energy of the particle cannot be measured ?  because it change on the frame we choosen..

Comment: No. In classical mechanics the energy can be measured exactly in any inertial frame. In quantum mechanics there is an uncertainty relation involving the energy, but you don’t worry about QM when considering a ball.

Comment: So we choose a inertial frame for measuring it?

Comment: Yes, just like you choose an inertial frame for measuring velocity, momentum, etc.